# Android Launcher App

Tags: android, launcher

I was able to create an app to be the default launcher of my android device using this intent filter on the manifest file:

```
<intent-filter>
   <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
   <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
   <category android:name="android.intent.category.HOME"/>
   <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
</intent-filter>
```

Everything works perfectly so once I click on the home button my app launches. The only problem I get is when I keep pressing repeatedly on back button (which I need to have it functional) I end up at Samsung default **TouchWiz** launcher.

My question is:
Is there any way to prevent my device from returning back to Samsung's **TouchWiz** default launcher?

I'm pretty sure that this is possible as I've seen different launchers on play store doing the same thing I want to achieve.

Regards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After investigating on this matter i came up with a solution. The trick was to override the method `onBackPressed()` of the **Activity** Class in the main activity of the launcher **Android** and just having it empty like so :

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    //do nothing
}
```

By doing this, whenever we are on the launcher's main activity the user won't get back to the OS launcher because the **Back Button** have no action.